# $regex within $project mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a `users` collection which has a location field with type `String`. I want to pass a score field along the document which shows whether the document's location is similar to the text "Austin". For instance the recorded location is **Austin, Texas**, I want it to be matched with **Austin**. I thought it would be possible to use *$regex* for this.

I wrote this aggregation:

```
$project: {
  score: {
    $cond: 
      if: {
        $regex: {'$location': /Austin/}
      },
      then: 1,
      else: 0
    }
  },
  location: 1,
  firstName: 1,
  lastName: 1
}
```

But what I get is :

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "errmsg": "exception: invalid operator '$regex'",
    "code": 15999,
    "ok": 0
}
```

Comment: `$cond: {if: then: else} ` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Still the same error

Comment: $location should be in position of 'score' as 'location'

Comment: any sample data? I can't guess what is score looks like, and how you want it.

Comment: I actually said a sample. "Austin, Texas" is a data. And for example user searches for "Austin" It seems that it is just possible with regex. And regex is not an aggregation operator.

Comment: looks like $regex does not support in $project, might need to use mapReduce to build another table.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but since version 4.2 you can use [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/).

You can use this stage:

```
{
  $project: {
    score: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $regexMatch: {
            input: "$location",
            regex: "Austin"
          }
        },
        then: 1,
        else: 0
      }
    },
    location: 1,
    firstName: 1,
    lastName: 1
  }
}
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zhZPRA8wR0c)