# Unable to use $regex in mongoose in aggregation query?

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting an error while using $regex in mongoose aggregation query . I am getting an invalid operator with error no 15999 . Please help  guys.

```
{ $match: { "_id": ObjectId(req.headers.token) } }, {
                        $project: {
                            inventory: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: '$inventory',
                                    as: 'inventory',
                                    cond: {$or:[{"$$inventory.item":new RegExp('^'+req.query.text+'$', "i")},{"$$inventory.sku":new RegExp('^'+req.query.text+'$', "i")}]}
                                }
                            },
                            _id: 0
             }
  }
```

Comment: you can consider req.query.text as string

Comment: If you can use JS code, try escaping it as `req.query.text.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')`. If the text contains `[` or `(` or other special regex metacharacters, this should fix the issue.

Comment: Not sure if you can use regex in $project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866336/regex-within-project-mongodb-aggregation

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in $match and you will get your result as in this example

```
Pincodes.aggregate([
{ "$match": { "district": new RegExp('^' + req.query.district, "i") } 
},
{ "$group": { "_id": "$district" } }])
.exec((err, data) => {
if (err) {
res.status(500).json({
data: err
})
}
else {
res.status(200).json({
data: data
})
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing just  `agg.match({'<fieldName'>:new RegExp('^' + req.query.district, "i")})` didnt work for me

I had to use eval in the solution.
if you are JSON.stringifying the aggregate query to see the output you won't see the effect of eval. Eval will have an effect later on when passed down to mongo.

```
agg.match({'<fieldName'>:eval(new RegExp('^' + req.query.district, "i"))});
```